# How to pass data to another page in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, frontend, web-frontend

this is my Name.js file
I want to send the API response data 'name' to another page how can I send this data to another page.
I want to store that data on another page, I have tried different methods but I am not getting
'''

```
const Test =  () => {
        const [name, setname] = useState("");
        const [firstname, setfirstname] = useState("");

     const  handleSubmit = async e => {
       e.preventDefault(); 
       var axios = require('axios');
        var data = JSON.stringify({"firstname":firstname,});

        var config = {
          method: 'post',
          url: 'URL',
          headers: { 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          data : data
        };

        axios(config)
        .then(function (response) {
          setname(response.data.ERR)
          console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
       
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });

        
          };
return (
<div></div>
)
}
```

'''

Comment: You can store that data globally if you are using redux or can pass that data through route.

Comment: can you share the code for that? How to share the date with the route.@DivyanSoni

Comment: are you using react-router ?

Comment: yes, I am using

Comment: you can use history.push({pathname: "/another-page", state: {name: name}}) and get the value in AnotherPageComponent by using location.state.name

Comment: I am getting error unexpected use of location
I have used as const {s} = location.state.name

Comment: can you please help me in this I am struggling for this from a lot of time @DivyanSoni

Comment: Can u share your code  so I can see what you are doing wrong ?

Comment: In AnotherPageComponent either use props.location.state.name or if using hooks then do this:-  import {useLocation} from "react-router-dom";  const location =useLocation (); location.state.name

Comment: thank u so much for the help,